# android studio relativelayout cannot morphing

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, morphing

My android studio cannot change from relativelayout to other layouts, and other layouts' morphing option don't have linearlayout. Does anyone has the same problem?

In the "Component Tree" right click the layout or widget there is an option "Morphing" that can change to other layout, But when it's relativelayout this option is disappeared.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Can you explain what you mean by "morphing" and possibly edit with some relevant code?

Comment: when i built a new project, the activity_main.xml's default layout is relativelayout, but i want to change to linearlayout. And at Component Tree  there is an option "Morphing" can change the layout. However  when layout is relativelayout the  "Morphing" optioin will disappear.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also looking for Morphing today.  When I Googled it, I found an issue in the Android Open Source Project... [Layout Morphing in Component Tree](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81754)